# Content boundary with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, firefox, rounded-corners

I am using CSS rounded corners for firefox and I have the following problem with content boundaries:

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      #outter {
            width: 200px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        }
        #inner {
            background: red;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Effect**

[alt text http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/2108/testew.png](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/2108/testew.png)

I can avoid this problem by defining `-moz-border-radius` for each outter's child. There is any other way I am missing?

***Edit***

A harder test with multiple inner divs with different `background-color` for each one:

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner1" style="background: blue">text</div>
    <div id="inner2" style="background: gray">text</div>
    ...
    <div id="innerN" style="background: yellow">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
  #outter {
        width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        background: red;
    }
    #inner {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Moving the background to the rounded parent will render correctly, see here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mE8En/ (only works in firefox!) add the webkit border radius if you want to support other [webkit based browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based_browsers) as well, like this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
```

**Update for edit:** To handle the inner divs in firefox subtract a pixel on the inner div to compensate for the border, resulting in this:

```
#outter {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    background: red;
}
#outter > div:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
}
#outter > div:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}
#inner {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
​
```

Note: the radii aren't perfect on the inner divs in webkit, adjust as desired...this is because the rendering isn't pixel perfect between browsers.

Comment: So, **defining the background on the element with the border**. (And by `other browsers` you mean webkit-based ones. :P)

Comment: Your solution obviously works for this simple example. And what about multiple inner divs?

Comment: For multiple inner divs, just change the id to a class and copy paste your html :)

Comment: @sr pt - Yep, I guess I take for granted what the `-webkit` means webkit browsers, updated in case that's not obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for all comments and sorry about the lack of information on my last comment. Please read my post edit for more information.

Comment: @Rui in that case, some other CSS3 styling is in order: http://jsfiddle.net/mE8En/2/

Comment: @Nick that was what i was trying to avoid and the reason i made this question on stackoverflow :P But I am afraid there is no other solution. Ty Nick :)

Comment: @Rui - Welcome :)  Hopefully once CSS3 is a spec/implemented we can use one border property, one day...

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want these rounded corners in IE without images, check out [DDRoundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/).